# Django loses permission to my email after an amout of time

Tags: python, django, email, reset-password

I created a couple of urls so that user can reset his password in case he forgot what it was,
In the process website should send a mail to the user's registered email to reset his password.
The function works well! But after an amount of time I get a timeoutError, I think because django loses permission to access my email from which it will send mails to the users emails.

The error I face:

```
TimeoutError at /password-reset/
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/password-reset/
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: TimeoutError
Exception Value:    
[WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Here is where I configured how to send mails in settings.py

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'MY EMAIL'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'A password that was generated by google app passwords'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'noreply<no_reply@domain.com>'
```

password_reset.html

```
{% extends 'retinoscope/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
      <div class="forms-container">
        <div class="signin-signup">
          <form class="sign-in-form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="title">Forgot Password?</h2>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
              {{ form.email }}</div>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn solid"/>
            <div class="social-media">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panels-container">
        <div class="panel left-panel">
          <img src="{% static 'retinoscope/media/forget.png' %}" class="image" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
{% endblock %}
```

password_reset_done.html

```
{% extends "retinoscope/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <h3> An email has been sent with instructions to reset your password :)</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

I downloaded a package for verifying emails and I added it list of apps in settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest of applications',
    'verify_email.apps.VerifyEmailConfig',
]
```

Comment: would that length of time be [3 days](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout)?

Comment: does it ever work, or does it always time out? I don't think gmail lets you send emails from a localhost, or any host for that matter. You should probably use a mail service instead, like Mailgun, sendgrid or mailchimp. These tend to have a 'free' / trial account you can use for low volume.

Comment: @Sayse No, It's much less than 3 days. I can have permission and all is working and in the same day it gives me Timeout error.

Comment: @MrE No it does work. I can send verification mails but after an amount of time I get this error and whenever I generate a new password and update my settings.py I regain the permission. Thank you for the suggestions tho, I will look into them.

Comment: what exactly times out? you /password-reset API call times out, but it's something within that call that actually times out, right? Can you identify what call that is and print out the response to the call. Is your service not able to join the host (that's usually when call timeout) if it was unauthorized, it would return right away with an error, not timeout after some time. You need to figure if it is a networking issue, an auth issue, or something else.